# How to fix a bug in my text calculator? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to make a really simple text calculator but I keep running into this problem.

Here is my code:

```
num1 = input("Enter in the first number")
num2 = input("Enter in the second number")
sign = input("Enter in the calculator operator you would like")

elif sign = "+":
   print(num1 + num2)
elif sign = "-":
   print(num1 - num2)
elif sign = "*":
   print(num1*num2)
elif sign = "/":
   print(num1/num2)
```

Sorry im new to python...

Comment: My bug is that it keeps telling me the difference between int and str.. but im quite confused.

Comment: Maybe read numbers as integers? *".. I keep running into this problem."* does not help us understand your problem. You also have an `elif` without `if`, and you don't use equality operator to check equals.

Comment: This should not have been closed; There are multiple issues. Just fixing `input` as `int()` does not resolve the users issues.

Comment: @PacketLoss That a question has multiple issues does not imply that it does not close, the first is a duplicate and the second a typo. Do you think this question will serve the community?

Comment: @eyllanesc The question likely does not serve much purpose outside of this issue. However it is a good starting point to help the poster learn. My reference was the question is closed as a `duplicate` to `int(input())` when however, that answer will not fix the issues the poster is having. It is part of the issue, however the code still fails with that resolved.

Comment: 1) change to `numX =float(input("Enter in the first number"))`, 2) change to `if sign == "Y":

Comment: @PacketLoss For the typo  just one comment is enough as the SO rules indicate. For a question to remain open it must contribute to the community, in this case the 2 problems do not contribute since the first is a known error (it has n duplicates) and the second is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code is not working is because you are simply multiplying/dividing/adding/subtracting your two numbers that are as of now declared as a string.

In python, you cannot add/subtract/multiply/divide strings as an integer. You need to declare your num1 and num2 as integers.

```
num1 = int(input("Enter in your first number"))
num2 = int(input("Enter in your second number"))
sign = input("Enter in the calculator operator you would like")

if sign == "+":
   print(num1 + num2)
elif sign == "-":
   print(num1 - num2)
elif sign == "*":
   print(num1*num2)
elif sign =="/":
   print(num1/num2)
```

Comment: The code will still fail due to syntax and operator errors. However this does solve part of the problem.

Comment: Remember to also compare your if statements with two equal signs "==" or else it will not work. Your first if statement is starting with an "elif". Remember to make it "if".

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few syntax errors in your code, check the comments to see where you could improve, with some reading material at the bottom!

```
num1 = int(input("Enter in the first number")) # You need to cast your input to a int, input stores strings.
num2 = int(input("Enter in the second number")) # Same as above, cast as INT
sign = input("Enter in the calculator operator you would like")

# You cannot use `elif` before declaring an `if` statement. Use if first!

if sign == "+": # = will not work, you need to use the == operator to compare values
   print(num1 + num2)
elif sign == "-": # = will not work, you need to use the == operator to compare values
   print(num1 - num2)
elif sign == "*": # = will not work, you need to use the == operator to compare values
   print(num1*num2)
elif sign == "/": # = will not work, you need to use the == operator to compare values
   print(num1/num2)
```

Code will work fine with these changes, however you should read up on [Python Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_syntax.asp) and [Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp)!

Happy learning!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because input by default gives a String. You have to convert it into int before using it.

```
num1 = int(input("Enter in the first number"))
num2 = int(input("Enter in the second number"))
sign = input("Enter in the calculator operator you would like")

if sign == "+":
   print(num1 + num2)
elif sign == "-":
   print(num1 - num2)
elif sign == "*":
   print(num1*num2)
elif sign == "/":
   print(num1/num2)
```

Comment: is valid this code: `if sign = "+":`?

Comment: unfortunately this still won't work because you need to compare the two values with "==" not "=".